# OAuth2 in Reactive spring security - Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, reactive

I have implemented an auth-server built on spring-boot, oauth2 with below end-points:

1. /oauth/token
2. /oauth/check_token
3. /oauth/token_key

I am trying to integrate this auth-server in one of my reactive resource server.
Tried below config:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:9001/oauth/token
      client:
        provider:
          custom-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9001/oauth/token
            token-uri: http://localhost:9001/oauth/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9001/auth/oauth/authorize
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:9001/auth/user/me
            user-name-attribute: name
        registration:
          custom-client:
            client-id: USER_CLIENT_APP
            client-secret: password
            client-name: Auth Server
            # scope: user_info
            provider: custom-provider
            # redirect-uri-template: http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: password
```

And below SecurityConfig

```java
@Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("role_admin")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.turtlemint'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.RELEASE")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.1-jre'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    //implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test', version: '3.1.0.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '3.2.4'
    compile group: 'org.junit', name: 'junit5-engine', version: '5.0.0-ALPHA'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-resource-server', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-jose', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.2.2.RELEASE'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoderByIssuerUri' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/reactive/ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerJwkConfiguration$JwtConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.ReactiveJwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoderByIssuerUri' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:9001/oauth/token"
```

As per my research, what I found was that the issuer-api is the auth-servers config end-point (as per OIDC standards). If so, how do I expose the same in my auth-server?

I searched online, but most of the examples are using third party auth providers like Okta.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @Praveen Kamah, have you been able to solve this ? I'm running the same exact errors, not using third party provider. Any clue to troubleshoot this situation would be very generous of you !

Answer (score -4):

You can refer to the springboot sample application related to spring-security, [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.3.3.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-jwe) might be helpful in your case